# Responsivness for different screens

Tags: html, css

What should be the correct media query sizes for mobile, tablet and ipad screens to make things responsive for all screens.

```
.box1, .box2, .box3{
     background: #ffffff;
     color:#2d276b;
     width: 60%;
     margin-left: 1%;
     font-size: 13px;
     text-align:left;
     margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use media query.

Example like below

```
    /* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

  //CSS

}
```